# Count how many elements I have in a specific Node

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

Good evening, 
I have an XML template like this :

```
<Pedestrian Name='Kid'>
        <Initial_Position In_X='2' In_Y='2' />
        <Final_Position Fin_X='3' Fin_Y='3' Time='10' />
        <Final_Position Fin_X='4' Fin_Y='4' Time='12' />
    </Pedestrian>
    <Pedestrian Name='Mother'>
        <Initial_Position In_X='3' In_Y='3' />
        <Final_Position Fin_X='3' Fin_Y='3' Time='10' />
    </Pedestrian>
```

in which *"Final_Position"* appears in a random numbers of time.

My idea for the code is the following :

```
foreach (XElement pedestrian in doc.Root.Elements("Pedestrian"))
            {
                XElement initialPosition = pedestrian.Element("Initial_Position");
                name = (string)pedestrian.Attribute("Name");
                X1 = (int)initialPosition.Attribute("In_X");
                Y1 = (int)initialPosition.Attribute("In_Y");
                MessageBox.Show(name);
                int i = 0;
               int x = doc.Root.Elements("Pedestrian").Elements("Final_Position").Count();// nodeList.Count();

                MessageBox.Show("x = " +x.ToString());
                int[] X_fin = new int[x];
                int[] Y_fin = new int[x];
                int[] Time_fin = new int[x];

                foreach (XElement finpos in doc.Root.Elements("Pedestrian").Elements("Final_Position"))
                {
                    X_fin[i] = (int)finpos.Attribute("Fin_X");
                    Y_fin[i] = (int)finpos.Attribute("Fin_Y");
                    Time_fin[i] = (int)finpos.Attribute("Time");

                    i++;
                }

            }
```

In order to be able, at the end, to create an array of objects *Pedestrian* which takes name,Initial_Position(X1,Y1) and Final_Position(X_Fin,Y_Fin,Time_Fin).

The problem is that if I put some MessageBox.Show() in order to understand how the program is working the output is something like that :

```
Kid
2 2 
3 3 10 //
4 4 12 //
3 3 10 //final position of Kid + Mother
Mother
3 3
3 3 10 //
4 4 12 //
3 3 10 //
```

Moreover the size of the array X_Fin is 3 (the sum of all Final_Position in my file).

How can i correct it in order to have in *X_Fin* all the position of a given pedetrian? My idea was to create the object after the second *foreach*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication97
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = 
                "<Root>" +
                "<Pedestrian Name='Kid'>" +
                    "<Initial_Position In_X='2' In_Y='2' />" +
                    "<Final_Position Fin_X='3' Fin_Y='3' Time='10' />" +
                    "<Final_Position Fin_X='4' Fin_Y='4' Time='12' />" +
                "</Pedestrian>" +
                "<Pedestrian Name='Mother'>" +
                    "<Initial_Position In_X='3' In_Y='3' />" +
                    "<Final_Position Fin_X='3' Fin_Y='3' Time='10' />" +
                "</Pedestrian>" +
                "</Root>";

            XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);

            var results = root.Descendants("Pedestrian").Select(x => new
            {
                name = (string)x.Attribute("Name"),
                initialPosition = x.Elements("Initial_Position")
                   .Select(y => new { x = (int)y.Attribute("In_X"), y = (int)y.Attribute("In_Y") }).FirstOrDefault(),
                finalPosition = x.Elements("Final_Position")
                   .Select(y => new { x = (int)y.Attribute("Fin_X"), y = (int)y.Attribute("Fin_Y"), Time = (int)y.Attribute("Time")}).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's create an array of Pedestrians, that has an `InitialPosition.X` & `.Y` and an array of `FinalPositions` that has the X, Y and Time for each.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file); // or use your doc.Root instead
var peds = root.Elements("Pedestrian")
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Name = (string)p.Attribute("Name"),
        InitialPosition = new
        {
            X = (int)p.Element("Initial_Position").Attribute("In_X"),
            Y = (int)p.Element("Initial_Position").Attribute("In_Y")
        },
        FinalPositions = p.Elements("Final_Position")
                .Select(f => new
                {
                    X = (int)f.Attribute("Fin_X"),
                    Y = (int)f.Attribute("Fin_Y"),
                    Time = (int)f.Attribute("Time")
                }).ToArray()
    }).ToArray();
```

Now let's output the array of pedestrians and internal FinalPositions.

```
int totalFinals = 0;
foreach (var pedestrian in peds)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} has {1} final positions.", pedestrian.Name, pedestrian.FinalPositions.Length));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", pedestrian.InitialPosition.X, pedestrian.InitialPosition.Y));
    foreach (var final in pedestrian.FinalPositions)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", final.X, final.Y, final.Time));
    totalFinals += pedestrian.FinalPositions.Length;
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total final positions = {0}", totalFinals));
```

The output is as I think you expect

```
Kid has 2 final positions.
2 2
3 3 10
4 4 12
Mother has 1 final positions.
3 3
3 3 10
Total final positions = 3
```